# How can I add a HDMI port to my PC running Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: hdmi

My PC doesn't have a HDMI port. Would like to add one so I can display video from my PC on my TV. Bought a card that provides the port but the software that came with it is for Windows. Am running Ubuntu 16.04. 
Is a Ubuntu compatible card with a HDMI port available?

Comment: Way too little information. What card? Basically, most of them should be supported.

Comment: What card did you buy? What is your system? A laptop? What model? Please [edit] your question to provide enough details to help you.